# Query database ETags on RavenDb

Tags: ravendb

I have a scenario where two different nodes replicates data from a given database to each other, but only one will be producing data at once.

I would like to know if there is a way to query (via http or via the .net apis) the last etag replicated from the source and the last one received by the destination, so there I can turn on or off a node when a synchronization occurs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That information is available in the Raven/Sources/URL document, and you can read it like any other document.